# C# run defrag.exe remotely

Tags: c#, wmi

I am trying to create a utility to defrag all machine on my network.  I have had success using WMI's Defrag and DefragAnalysis methods, however they are not compatible with Windows XP.  This is a problem as we have some XP machines on the network.
I have been able to locally invoke the defrag.exe process on an XP machine to perform a defrag however I am having problem invoking it on remote machines.  Below is my code which works locally, could someone please help me in making this work for remote machines on my network?  I have tried using a bit of WMI to help out but as I am new to C# and WMI I haven't had success, thanks!

```
ProcessStartInfo info = new ProcessStartInfo();
info.FileName = "defrag";
info.Arguments = volume + " -f";
info.UseShellExecute = false;
info.CreateNoWindow = true;
info.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Process defrag = Process.Start(info);
defrag.PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.BelowNormal;

while (!defrag.HasExited)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
    Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("dfrgntfs");
    if (procs != null && procs.Length > 0)
    {
        procs[0].PriorityClass = ProcessPriorityClass.Idle;
        defrag.WaitForExit();
    }

    result = null;
    while(!defrag.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
    {
        //get output and store results
    }
```

Comment: You might be using the wrong tool for the job in this case. try using `PSTools` http://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/sysinternals/bb897553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would probably just use [PsExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to run the command remotely. This should work for pretty much any Windows (NT) version.

Comment: Ok I have downloaded PsExec and think I have the first part of the code converted to using this method but am not sure about the section within my while loop (running the dfrgntf process). Here is what I have so far... Process psexec = new Process(); psexec.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\PsExec.exe"; psexec.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true; psexec.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false; psexec.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true; psexec.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\MyMachine C:\WINDOWS\system32\defrag.exe c: -f";

Comment: sorry I know that isn't the most readable but because I am a new user I am not able to answer my own question right now.

Comment: There seems to be a problem with this lines...
psexec.StartInfo.Arguments = @"\\MyMachine defrag.exe c: -f";
Do you see a problem here?

Comment: Figured it out, need the -s parameter before the remote machine to run in System account.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Just to complete this thread I thought I would post the code that actually worked for me, for this code to work you must download PsTools and place it in the root...

```
            Process psexec = new Process();

            psexec.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\PsExec.exe";
            psexec.StartInfo.Arguments = @"-s \\" + machine + " defrag.exe " + volume + " -f";
            psexec.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            psexec.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            psexec.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            psexec.Start();

            while (!psexec.HasExited)
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);

                Process[] procs = Process.GetProcessesByName("dfrgntfs", @"\\" + machine);
                if (procs != null && procs.Length > 0)
                {
                    psexec.WaitForExit();
                }

                while (!psexec.StandardOutput.EndOfStream)
                {
                    //get output and store results
                }
```